# enum of objects in swagger UI?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have an enum of other definitions in my Swagger spec:

```
"action": {
  "title": "Action",
  "description": "Action to apply to matching requests",
  "type": "object",
  "enum": [ 
    {"delayAction": {"$ref": "#/definitions/delayAction"}}, 
    {"abortAction": {"$ref": "#/definitions/abortAction"}},
    {"traceAction": {"$ref": "#/definitions/traceAction"}}
  ]
}
```

and `delayAction`, `abortAction`, and `traceAction` are all defined.

But in the Swagger UI the model for `action` is empty.

[image]

How can I modify my Swagger definition so Swagger UI can show the definition of `action` in the model?

Comment: What happens if you define them inline rather than in definitions?

Comment: Do you mean that `action` can be an instance of either `delayAction`, `abortAction` or `traceAction` schema? If yes, can you also post the definitions of those schemas?

Comment: I know this probably wasn't supported 6 years ago :) but now you should use the oneOf directive instead of an enum of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think enums can be defined only as object literals.
Checkout this example it seems to explain quite well with an example.

https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/Enum-of-defined-objects/m-p/198117/highlight/true#M988